# Putting FOREIGN and UNIQUE at same column

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I try put a column like a `Unique KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`, then when I have a column like `Unique` and after I run this line in `mysql`:

```
ALTER TABLE table
ADD FOREIGN KEY(id) 
REFERENCES main_table(id)
```

nothing happens, and if I try alter the table to `Unique` when the column is `FOREIGN KEY`, then the `FOREIGN KEY` disappears.

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  Adding a foreign key constraint doesn't exactly cause fireworks to go off.

Comment: i want reference a column `ID` for `Main_Table` and `table`, but i want uniques ID in `table`

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.  Please show minimal sample schemas for the two tables, and show how you know there's a problem.